The existence of some kernel on Riemannian manifolds
We know that heat kernels $K_{t}(x,y)$ exist on Riemannian manifolds with following properties:

$\Delta_{x}K_{t}=\Delta_{y}K_{t}$
$K_{0}(x,y)=\delta_{y}(x)$

However, for fixed $y$ the support of $f(x)=K_{t}(x,y)$ doesn't shrink with respect to time but suddenly collapse to $y$. I am wondering does there exist a family of kernel $\eta_{t}(x,y)$ similar to heat kernel i.e. preserves properties 1),2), additionally, for any fixed $y$, whose supports gradually shrink to $y$ rather than a sudden collapse as time approaches $0$.

It's the unphysical feature of the heat kernel wrt. to Brwonian motion, that its support grows from a point at $t=0$ to the whole manifold in zero time. The reason is its meaning as a transition probability, that represents independent paths and increments down to time and distance zero, a feature essential for its use in differentiable manifolds.
